# How do I count the number of elements in a sortable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple divs in an HTML document with smaller divs within them that can be sorted among each other. When the document is loaded, a random amount of those smaller divs are appended to #boxtop.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script link src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type" type="text/css" href = "style.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div id = "boxtop" class = "dragInto"></div>
    <button type="button" id="button">My Children!!!</button>
    <div id = "eqbox"></div>
    <div id = "box1" class = "ansBox"></div>
    <div id = "box2" class = "ansBox"></div>
    <div id = "box3" class = "ansBox"></div>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my relevent jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#boxtop").sortable
    ({
        connectWith: ".ansBox"          
    });

    $(".ansBox").sortable
    ({
        connectWith: ".ansBox"          
    });

});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("dragInto").droppable
    ({
        accept: ".box"
    });
});

var numChild = $("#boxtop").length;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function() 
    {
        console.log(numChild);
    });
});
```

My question is: How can I get the number of elements in a sorted div. I currently try and print that value to the console using numChild but that prints "1". And if I were to drag a bunch of elements from #boxtop to .box1, how could I get the number of elements inside .box1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.length` property tells you how many elements belong to the jQuery object you call it on. So given that `$("#boxtop")` matches one element, `$("#boxtop").length` will be 1.

To find out how many elements are inside `#boxtop` you have to select all of its descendants and *then* check the `.length`:

```
// All descendants:
$("#boxtop").find("*").length    // or:
$("#boxtop *").length

// Or count immediate children only:
$("#boxtop").children().length
```

In your case I think checking immediate children is probably what you want. But don't set a global variable like:

```
var numChild = $("#boxtop").children().length;
```

...because that will set `numChild` to the length when the page first opens, before the user has started interacting with it. You need to check `$("#boxtop").children().length` or `$(".box1").children().length` at the point where the value is needed.

As an aside, you don't need three separate `$(document).ready(...)` handlers: combine all of your code into a single ready handler, or if you put your `<script>` element at the end of the body you don't need a ready handler at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Works as Intend now. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch `update` or `stop` event from `sortable` instance. Detailed document just right there

- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop
- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

[Live Demo And Working Code](https://codepen.io/stevngo/pen/KyPZqQ)